# Сложить два двоичных числа

Tags: числа, информатика

Скорее, вопрос по информатике. Пожалуйста, помогите сложить два двоичных числа в форме с плавающей запятой.

```
1-е число: мантисса = 0,11101 порядок 101  
2-е число: мантисса = 0,11011 порядок 011
```

Я правильно понимаю, что сначала мы нормализуем порядки путем сдвига в сторону большего числа? И это вроде как применяется только для *2-го числа*:

```
0,11011 порядок 011 => 0,01011 порядок 101
```

Дальше мы должны сложить мантиссы - и с этим у меня проблема! Пожалуйста, помогите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сдвинуть мантиссу числа с меньшим порядком вправо на разницу порядков. Здесь второе на два разряда вправо

```
0,11101
0,0011011
```

А сложение, как обычно в столбик (лишние разряды справа могут обрезаться или округляться, если точность не позволяет их вместить)

```
0,11101
0,00110
--------
1,00011    порядок 101
или после нормализации
0,10001    порядок 110
```

Comment: Лишние разряды не обязательно обрезаются, это нужно уточнять у автора вопроса. В стандарте IEEE-754, например, по-умолчанию идёт округление nearest-to-even, то есть второе число будет `0,00111`. Если же нужен более точный ответ, то правильнее будет обрезать разряды ПОСЛЕ сложения, именно так делается в арифметике в процессоре. То есть я бы правильный ответ написал иначе: `1,00100` порядок `101`. Если надо нормализовать, автор сообразит.

Comment: Про обрезку добавил уточнение, про остальное - пока не уверен, что  автору такие тонкости нужны.